# empirical t-values with bootsempls in R, transform console output to vector

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, structural-equation-model

If I run bootsempls() function of the semPLS package in R, I get an object of class "bootsempls", "boot", lets name the object "mymodel_boot".

If I run

```
>mymodel_boot

         Estimate      Bias Std.Error Lower Upper
lam_1_1     0.923 -0.000188   0.01400 0.892 0.946
lam_1_2     0.918 -0.000971   0.01778 0.876 0.945
lam_2_1     0.860 -0.001325   0.02647 0.799 0.903
lam_2_2     0.897  0.000579   0.01604 0.864 0.926
lam_2_3     0.799 -0.000253   0.03476 0.723 0.859
lam_3_1     0.793 -0.003462   0.06742 0.636 0.897
lam_3_2     0.942  0.001877   0.00892 0.927 0.963
beta_1_3    0.429  0.003359   0.07722 0.280 0.579
beta_2_3    0.294 -0.000880   0.07339 0.147 0.435
```

I get the table above.

To compute t-values, I now want to divide the original coefficients by the corresponding standard error.

The original coefficients can be targeted by

```
> mymodel_boot$t0
[1] 0.9227120 0.9180390 0.8599884 0.8973823 0.7993398 0.7927142 0.9424423 0.4292315 0.2941801
```

Is there any way to target the Std.Error like that, which is printed in the previous codeblock, so I could just divide these and get a vector of t-values?

I have read the help page of bootsempls, but can't find a component that returns only the Std.Err and now I am confused, because I thought its a common procedure to estimate t-values and there is no smarter way than to copy paste each Std.Err from the console? I can't believe that.

If the Std.Err can't be targeted through the $ operator, is there any way I can transform the Std.Err column in the console output into a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The usual way is to use `attributes` and `str` in order to find such attributes in unknown classes (I guess this is how you found `t0`?), but this resulted in nothing for me. So I've decided to check the print method. A quick look at

```
methods(print)
```

Showed me `print.bootsempls*`

Next step was:

```
getAnywhere(print.bootsempls)
```

Which resulted in:

```
A single object matching ‘print.bootsempls’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for print from namespace semPLS
  namespace:semPLS
with value

function (x, digits = 3, ...) 
{
    t <- x$t
    t0 <- x$t0
    result <- data.frame(Estimate = t0, Bias = colMeans(t, ...) - 
        t0, Std.Error = apply(t, 2, sd, ...))
    rownames(result) <- attr(t, "path")
    cat("Call: ")
    dput(x$call)
    cat("\n")
    print(result, digits = digits, ...)
    invisible(x)
}
<environment: namespace:semPLS>
```

Which solved the mystery. So apperantly the print method calculates the S.E. and it isn't stored anywhere. In order to replicate the output you showed and store it as a `data.frmae` object (and also to calculate S.E.) you will have to simply do the following:

```
t <- mymodel_boot$t
t0 <- mymodel_boot$t0
result <- data.frame(Estimate = t0, 
                     Bias = colMeans(t) - t0,
                     Std.Error = apply(t, 2, sd))
```

Comment: (+1) for doing the hard work...these print methods that dont return are a minor irritation ;), but i think you can get the estimates from the `summary`. Using the first example from `?bootsempls` this seems to work; `str(s <- summary(ecsiBoot)`. You can then get estimates from `s$table`

Comment: @user20650, thanks. I didn't see that one, but my guess is that if the OP only needs the S.E., it will probably more efficient for him to just do `apply(mymodel_boot$t, 2, sd)` than calculating the `summary`, as `summary` probably doing many additional/unnecessary calculations too.

Comment: either way is perfectly fine, thank you both very much.